# ModelCheckpoint doesn't save the model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, speech

I am trying to build a speech recognition model following this tutorial
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/learn-build-first-speech-to-text-model-python/
there is 2 part, the first is a training model which output is the input of the second part ( testing model)

at the end of the training model, there is this part which should save the result of the training

```
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, min_delta=0.0001) 
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

so the result should be saved in this file "best_model.hdf5"
this model run without any error but I didn't found any file created 
when I tried to load the model in testing model, I got an error message that this file wasn't found

any help please ?

keras version installed: 2.3.1

update 1:
I tried to know the location at which your code is running using:

`print(os.getcwd())`

I got the same direction of model file, I tried to put this location in the code to save in it and to load from it but still there is no file created and I got the same error message

update 2:
I add
`print(os.listdi())`
after ModelCheckpoint function and also I didn't find it

Comment: use import os and then print(os.getcwd()) this should give you the location at which your code is running. Or create a file with full path appended to it.

Comment: I tired it
I got the same direction of model file, I tried to put this location in the code  to save in it and to load from it but still there is no file created and I got the same error message

Comment: Please update your post to actually **show** the approach suggested by @High-Octane above along with the results of `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir` (I guess you actually run `model.fit` before looking for the file, right?)

Comment: I updated it,
I tried ```print(os.listdi()) ``` and I didn't found it,
for ```model.fit``` it is used in the trying model not training model

Comment: sorry, I got confused, model.fit() it is used before looking for the file, it is in the training model not testing

Answer (score 0):

How about try to define the checkpoint_file_path separately and use that variable in the function call? This mostly happens because of the "/" before the file path name. so you can try  "/best_model.hdf5"

Comment: thank you for your comment, I tried to put the full path but still the problem exit 
`es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, min_delta=0.0001) `
`mc = ModelCheckpoint('/home/moataz/Desktop/speech/Model/best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')`

I think the problem is in the parameter like verbose and monitor because I tried to change one of them and it works and the file is created but the model saved wasn't good